# Query Collection contents in Python client for Google Docs API

Tags: google-docs-api

How do I query the contents of a specific collection using the Python client for Google Docs API?
This is how far I've come:

```
client = gdata.docs.service.DocsService()
client.ClientLogin('myuser', 'mypassword')

FOLDER_FEED1 = "/feeds/documents/private/full/-/folder"
FOLDER_FEED2 = "/feeds/default/private/full/folder%3A"

feed    = client.Query(uri=FOLDER_FEED1 + "?title=MyFolder&title-exact=true")
full_id = feed.entry[0].resourceId.text
(res_type, res_id) = full_id.split(":")

feed    = client.Query(uri=FOLDER_FEED2 + res_id + "/contents")

for entry in feed.entry:.
    print entry.title.text
```

The first call to `Client.Query` succeeds and seems to provide a valid resource ID. The second call, however, returns:

```
{'status': 400, 'body': 'Invalid request URI', 'reason': 'Bad Request'}
```

- How can I correct this to get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is much easier once you have a folder entry, to call `client.GetResources(entry.content.src)` rather than generating the URI by yourself and using a Query.

In your case, `client.GetResources(feed.entry[0].content.src)`.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. GetResources() seems to be a method of the class 'DocsClient' rather than of the class 'DocsService' that I'm currently using. I guess I've two questions: 1) How do you share state (i.e. authorization) between the two objects, so that you can first do a Query() and than proceed with a GetResources() as you suggest 2) What is the reason that DocsClient and DocsService are different classes, i.e. what is the relationship and when should you use either of these classes?

Comment: You shouldn't be using the DocsService, it is deprecated and unsupported. I strongly recommend you move over.

Comment: Thanks Ali, that's helpful information. Maybe you can mention this somewhere in the documentation as well?